# Act on database before Unit Test loads data from [DataSource], or manually set TestContext.DataRows

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datasource

I'd like to run a stored procedure in my database prior to loading test data from a [DataSource] in a Unit Test. This procedure takes a parameter that is specific to each test method.

How can I call the sp once per Test Method? I tried doing it in an attribute, which worked, but it's messy.

Alternatively, and this is what I'm really trying to do here, is there a way to load test data from SQL Server dynamically, or possibly intercept the sql call that Unit Test makes on a per TestMethod basis?

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract how you get your test data with a wrapper.  Instead of calling `TestContext.DataRow[dataRowColumnName]` directly wrap it with a new class.  In this wrapper class you can override the values or use the test data from the database.

Comment: unfortunately its not the values i'm worried about. it's the actual rows that i get back. my proc is meant to run some filtering that will add in/cut out rows before the test method is ever entered

Comment: Have you tried running your proc in the ClassInitialize method? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That's more or less what I went with.